# spring-boot-jpa Initial Entity Persistence

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to figure out how, in the lifecycle of a Spring Boot application, to conditionally persist a single entity when the application starts up.    The normal method of loading initial data via 'import.sql' or similar methods is no good in this use case, because the insert is conditional.   On start up, I'd like for my application to check and see if an admin account and the associated admin role exists.  If neither exists, I'd like the application to create them.  If they do exist, I'd like the application to do nothing and leave the existing entities alone.   If I use the import.sql method, I'll either wind up with a duplicate key (username=admin) or I'll overwrite the existing admin account, which may have had it's password changed away from the default password by a previous installation of the application.

I've tried using ApplicationListeners for all the default Spring and Spring Boot events, and I get null pointer exceptions for every one of those listeners because the JPA repositories are not yet initialized. I thought that listeners invoked for the ContextRefreshedEvent were supposed to be called after all beans and such are initialized, but I guess I'm wrong about that.   I've also tried to create a bean which has a @PostConstruct annotated method which does this entity creation, however I had the same result with the JPA CrudRepositories not being initialized.

So my base question is; "What is the preferred entry point for doing initialization work with JPA CrudRepositories during Spring Boot application start up?"

Answer (score 0):

`ContextRefreshedEvent` would normally work (so you may have an initialization ordering problem with your listener). You can also use `SmartInitializingSingleton` or a `SmartLifecycle` with autostart=true. In a Spring Boot app you also have `CommandLineRunner`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that _ContextRefreshedEvent_ **should** work.  That got me looking into things a little bit deeper.  The problem wasn't specifically with JPA.  Anything that was `@Autowired`, `@Inject`ed, or `@Value`d into the _ApplicationListener_ implementation was null when the implementation actually ran.  

I circumvented this by not using autowiring, and pulling what I needed out of the _ApplicationContext_ passed in with the _Event_.  That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Yeah that would work. Spring has no choice but to instantiate `ApplicationListeners` early (because there are events that precede the one you happen to be interested in). So that would explain the missing dependencies.